# Symfony 3 Generating Entities from Multiple Databases on Same Connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out how symfony can work with multiple databases on one mysql server. I have a mysql server with many databases on it, and those many databases have many tables. Some of the tables in different databases can relate to each other. Normally I would query like this:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM db1.users as u
JOIN db2.whatever as w ON w.user_id = u.id
```

Now I'm trying to use Symfony. I've got multiple connections set up like it says in http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html because I do have multiple database servers I have to hit. That works fine for hitting that one dbname on each connection. But there are many "dbnames" I need to hit for each connection.

I've learned from here https://techpunch.co.uk/development/using-multiple-databases-with-symfony2-and-doctrine2 that I can use mutiple databases in the notations on the entities. But I'm trying to run the doctrine:mapping:import, and it only works on whatever is the dbname in the configuration.

Is there any way to tell it "all the databases on this connection", or give it a list of ones to use, or any way of telling it to use other databases on the same server/connection? The only thing I can think of so far is "change the dbname in the config, run it again, repeat". All the questions and answers I'm finding so far in google and here have to do with using a different entity manager/connection.

Comment: Basically it is one entity manager per database.  You can "trick" it into joining across multiple databases by using the database name as part of your table name i.e. db1.table1, db2.table2 etc.  But most of the utilities will no longer work and of course you end up hard coding database names directly into the mapping.  One approach that sometimes works is to have one master database and define views in it that access the other databases.  Of course views have their own limitations.  Just the way it is.

Comment: So if you have an existing project that uses many databases and you want to use symfony, what do you do? What's the common solution?

Comment: I suspect there is no common solution.  The Doctrine ORM does a good job for what it is designed for but does not do well outside of it's box.  There is a Doctrine Database Access Layer which simplifies using sql.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/  ORM's in general seldom work well for more complex problems.

Comment: For generating entities, just change the default entity manager manually and generate each database separately.  Then just make sure your table names in the ORM all have the database name prefixing them.

Comment: Jason, any idea what things that would break? I'm thinking about just making separate entity managers for the common tables and then just using raw SQL when I really need to reach to something else. I don't want to fight the framework.